How to remove or customize the background circle behind the selected item in BottomNavigationView?
I am using a BottomNavigationView in my Android application. When an item is selected, a small circular (or oval) background appears behind the selected item. By default, this background is a dark color. I want to either remove this effect entirely or customize its color.
Here is the current XML code for my BottomNavigationView:
<com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
    android:id="@+id/bottom_navigation"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/bg_rounded"
    app:itemBackground="@android:color/transparent"
    app:itemIconSize="40dp"
    app:itemIconTint="@color/selcetediconcolor"
    app:labelVisibilityMode="labeled"
    app:menu="@menu/menu_main" />


